# It's not scrollable vertically in case of LiveCharts in WrapPanel of WPF,

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I implemented the presentation of several charts by the `LiveChart` in ListBox.
It works well. It's displayed by wrapping charts on page space automatically. But, It's not scrollable vertically.

It's scrollable horizontaly when I set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` as `Enabled` as 1 line with a horizontal scrollbar.

But, It is not the result what i want by using the `wrapPanel`.

Do you have this kind of experience? Please help me.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding info}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Width="350" Height="250">
        <lvc:CartesianChart>
          <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding data}"/>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
      </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Make sure that there is no `StackPanel` among the visual ancestors of the `ListBox`.

Comment: @mm8  I am sorry that it does not work yet when I try `StackPanel` in vertical orientation.

Comment: The comment was meant to say that there should *not* be a StackPanel. Neither as direct parent of the ListBox, nor somewhere higher in the visual tree. Use a Grid or DockPanel instead.

Comment: Yes. It's little bit complicated.   Now,  It is current hierarchy: `<Window><Grid><Grid><Frame><Page><StackPanel><ListBox><StackPanel><CartesianChart>`.

Comment: @yahocho: So remove the `StackPanel` from the `Page`.

Comment: @mm8 You are genius. Thank you very much. It works well.

Comment: @Clemens I thought that the reason was `livecharts`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't get a vertical scrollbar is that you have put the `ListBox` in a `StackPanel`. A `StackPanel` measures its children with infinite vertical space if its `Orientation` property is set to `Vertical`:

[It's not scrollable vertically in case of LiveCharts in WrapPanel of WPF,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166056/its-not-scrollable-vertically-in-case-of-livecharts-in-wrappanel-of-wpf?noredirect=1#comment98960004_56166056)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. It's why I am doing stackoverflow.